# Hibernate Invalid Path Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

New to Hibernate and HQL in general. I have these following entities.

#### Employee entity

```java
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private Integer authority;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person person;

    @Column
    private Integer gender;

    @Column
    private String ssn;

    @Column(name = "car_info")
    private String carInfo;

    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    private Date birthDate; //java.util Date vs java.sql.Date?

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "visa_status_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private VisaStatus visaStatus;

    @Column(name = "license_number")
    private Integer licenseNumber;

    @Column(name = "license_expiration_date")
    private Date licenseExpirationDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "housing_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private House house;
}
```

#### Person entity

```java
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "preferred_name")
    private String preferredName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "ceil_phone")
    private String ceilPhone;

    @Column(name = "work_phone")
    private String workPhone;

}
```

#### House entity

```java
public class House implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id",  referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contactHR;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "landlord_id")
    private Person landlord;
}
```

I'm trying to run this HQL:

```sql
select person from Employee where house.id=:houseId
```

I'm basically trying to get all the `Person` with the `houseId` from the `Employee`. Since I'm trying to only get the person, I'm using the `select` cause.

But I'm getting these errors:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'house.id'
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'house.id' [select person from example.project.domain.entity.Employee where house.id=:houseId]
```

I tried the HQL without the `select` clause and it worked:

```sql
from Employee where house.id=:houseId
```

But I only need `person` so I didn't want to get everything. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: add aliases: `select e.person from Employee e where e.house.id=:houseId`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov It actually worked! And I'm more confused... How did adding the alias resolve the issue. How does that even work?

Comment: The problem is you expectations are based on assumption that `JPQL` is some kind of "improved" `SQL` - that is wrong, moreover even in `SQL` specifying alias is a best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked

> **Hibernate** Invalid **Path Exception** using HQL

The problem lies on the written query

```
select person from Employee where house.id=:houseId
```

Which should contain proper referencing

```
select p.person from Employee p where p.house.id=:houseId
```

**Why ?**

The `FROM` clause defines which entities the data is going to be selected. Hibernate, or any other JPA implementation, maps the entities to the according database tables and the syntax of a JPQL `FROM` clause is similar to SQL and indeed uses the entity model for referencing database attributes, which in root query execution (same thing you are doing) one must use the same referencing strategy, which in your case is to use aliases, as [A.Panfilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309/andrey-b-panfilov) said in comments regardless of hibernate, even in aliasing in SQL is a [good](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5991) practice.

You may find more in [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/jpql/).